# Whats the right way to map path to image in MVC static method

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

Struggling with this for a bit... I read around SO and found that I should be using HostingEnvironment.MapPath().

Every time I try and use this method, though, I get told virtual path not allowed.

I have a file located under (project)\Content\Images\MyImage.jpg

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/") + "/Content/Images.cslogo_highres.jpg");
```

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\Images\cslogo_highres.jpg'.

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("Content") + "/Images/cslogo_highres.jpg");
```

> The relative virtual path 'Content' is not allowed here.

I tried a few other combinations, googled around a bit, but haven't been able to come up with something which works. I would really just like to use ResolveUrl(~/Content/Images/cslogo_highres.jpg) but it doesn't seem to be an option under a static method.

Sorry if this is trivial, but I got frustrated guess-and-checking paths.

EDIT: Answer, surprisingly not as succinct as one would expect:

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Images/cslogo_highres.jpg")));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Images/cslogo_highres.jpg")));
```

Comment: Page does not exist in this context.

Comment: Try now, wasn't sure what context that code is running in, I assume a controller?

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I should have been more clear. I checked your edit -- but no, Url isn't accessible from here, either. It did provide me with a new googleable term though which ended up yielding the correct answer. Marking you as correct for the help, editing the answer into original post.

Comment: Cool, going to change my answer to match your findings for others in the future.